# Graph representation of multi objective problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, scheduling, resource-scheduling

I'm investigating a possible research topic for a thesis project that involves a multi-objective scheduling problem and I'm wondering if anyone has ideas for representing such a problem as a graph.  I've looked at some literature on the subject and a common approach seems to be using cost vectors on the edges instead of a single cost number.   This makes sense to me but I don't see how I can model certain aspects of my problem this way.

In particular there are resources in the model that constrain each activity to certain time windows and a valid schedule must schedule each activity within these constraints.  Further, there are some sets of activities that are dependent on each other. For example a user can place time delta requirements between two activities saying they must be scheduled within some number of time units of each other or must be *at least* some number of time units apart in a valid schedule.  I can imagine modeling these as optional elements in a cost vector but is there a better way?

Bonus question is that this is also supposed to be a least commitment scheduler.  Each activity should be given some window that's nominally n time units long so there doesn't have to necessarily be a total order on activities.

Any literature on representing problems like this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a keyword for you to search for: *Constraint Programming*

You can model such problems as so-called constraint satisfaction problems, i.e. a bunch of variables, their possible values, and a set of constraints that your solution (=selection of values for the variables) has to satisfy.

With CP you can directly formulate your text above as individual constraints (f.ex., activity A has to be before activity B becomes something like A.endTime <= B.startTime).

As for literature, there are loads of books and papers on CP available, especially with a focus on scheduling (there's even a conference dedicated to CP for scheduling problems).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Job Shop Scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling): there are plenty of articles on that.